# RailsでGoogleMapを表示させたいです。

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

Ruby on Railsで開発をしています。
GoogleMapを表示させたいんですが、マップが表示されなくて、困っています。
viewコードとjsファイルのコードを書いておきますのでどう修正すればいいのか教えていただきたいです。

map.html.slimファイル

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta charset="utf-8"
    title ポリゴン
    sass:
      html, body
      　height: 100%
      　margin: 0
      　padding: 0

      div
        display: inline-block
        &#map
          height: 100%
          width:  640px
          margin: 0 auto
  body
    #map

  script src="/assets/admin/polygon.js"
  script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=init" async="async" defer="defer"
```

app/assets/javascripts/admin/polygon.jsファイル

```
var map;
var markers = [];
var polygons = [];
function init() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 35.783530, lng: 139.696165},
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false,
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', setMarker);
}

function setMarker(event){
  var latlng = createGmapLatLng(event.latLng.lat(),event.latLng.lng());
  mk = new google.maps.Marker({
      map:map,
      position: latlng,
  });
  mk.setMap(map);
  markers.push(latlng);
}

function createGmapLatLng(lat,lng){
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
  return latlng
}
```

Answer (score 1):

html, body に対しての css が効いていないので、表示されていないのでは？

```
html, body
height: 100%
margin: 0
padding: 0
```

ではなく、

```
html, body
  height: 100%
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
```

かと思います。

普通に表示すれば出てくるので

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map;
  function init() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 35.783530, lng: 139.696165},
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false,
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=init"></script>
```

## 追記

エラーが出ているのではありませんか？少なくとも私は出ました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

sass のコードの中に、全角空白が含まれていますよ？

Comment: cssのところは単純にここでの表示が間違っているだけです。編集しておきますので、他に気になるところがありましたら教えてください。

Comment: 回答を追記しました。リンク先を見ていただければわかりますが、rails や api の問題では無いので、もろもろ、正しく記述してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ですが、エラーは出ていませんし、ネットでマップだけ表示させる基本的なコードだけで試してみても全然地図が表示されません。「このページでは Google マップの要素を表示できませんでした。サイト管理者にお問い合わせください。ご自身がサイト管理者の場合は、JavaScript コンソールをご確認いただくか、次のトラブルシューティング ページをご覧ください」このようなメッセージが出たりしますね..

Comment: 何か環境の設定などが必要だったりはしませんか？一応開発環境としてはMacbook air、chrom、rubymineになっていますが..　もしくは必要なgemだったり。

Comment: そ、それはエラーメッセージというのでは……(´・ω・｀)。そのメッセージが出るということは、api にはメッセージが届いており、障害によってデータが返ってこない、ということです。コチラではそれ以上わからないので、指示通りに、トラブルシューティングに従ってください

Answer (score 0):

単純にAPIキーが指定されてないからではないですか？
公式サイトではscriptタグのクエリストリングにAPIキーが指定されています。
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial